# objects in String constant pool in java

Tags: java, scjp, ocpjp

```
public class NewClass {

    public String makinStrings() {
        String s = "Fred";
        s = s + "47";
        s = s.substring(2, 5);
        s = s.toUpperCase();
        return s.toString();
    }
}
```

How many objects are created in the above program? I see as 4 objects after converting to uppercase string, but the answer is 3 according scjp book. I don't understand how come only 3 objects

Comment: Please refer to any of the 750 "how many strings are created by this code" questions here on SO. Several of them have **very** thorough descriptions of what goes on, the last thing we need is yet another one.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0):

1. `s = "Fred"`
2. `s = s+47;` => `s = Fred47`
3. `s = s.substring(2,5);` => `s = ed4`
4. `s = s.toUpperCase();` => `s = ED4`

Comment: @Aniket: I figured out the same way and it adds up to 4 objects, but the answer is only 3 objects are created and you have posted the same thing

Answer (score -1):

Yes 3 objects

```
    String s = "Fred";             // created in pool
    s = s + "47";                  // created in heap
    s = s.substring(2, 5);         // created in heap
    s = s.toUpperCase();           // created in heap
```

If you see the source of `substring()` and `toUpperCase()` it returns a new string and `s + "47";` since the value of `s` is determined at runtime it willl create new string so a total of 3 objects.

Comment: can anybody explain me the reason for downvotes? did I say anything wrong

Comment: sorry I had to remove it as a answer because of downvotes and it made me think that may be your answer is wrong. Yes, even I would like people to comment instead of just down voting when I have already accepted it as an answer